# How to create foundation structure of my app

Tags: angular, angularjs, routes

I am making frontend for a web appp. I am a beginner. Gone through some tutorials and it will be my first project. So in this image you can see I have navbar on left or we cam implement it as left div with buttons to redirect to respective page in right div blue one. I can't figure out what to put where. Like let's suppose I make 3 commponent login, register, home. So now should I add the remaining compontnts like donations, tournaments inside home components or should I create these components in just components folder. Also if someone can give me some link to learning angular routes, I am struglling at it. Thanks in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2uCc.png)

I have made simple app with 3 components till now.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't understand your question. Are you trying to place some buttons in the navbar itself?
2. You should create separate components for each piece of functionality. But there's no right or wrong "way" to do this. Everyone has a different opinion on this.
3. Angular Route - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/11/a-complete-guide-to-routing-in-angular/
4. Angular Folder Structure - https://angular-folder-structure.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/

Comment: I am thinking on using navbar or div element with buttons to redirect to different views at right side. Which will work better?

Comment: Both approaches are fine. I would still prefer to use a navbar in this case.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please give an upvote.

Comment: @the_machinist Please write a comment if you don't understand the question before writing an answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).